# iPhone - AVAudioPlayer - convert decibel level into percent

Tags: iphone, core-audio, avaudioplayer, formula, decibel

I like to update an existing iPhone application which is using AudioQueue for playing audio files. The levels (peakPowerForChannel, averagePowerForChannel) were linear form 0.0f to 1.0f.

Now I like to use the simpler class AVAudioPlayer which works fine, the only issue is that the levels which are now in decibel, not linear from -120.0f to 0.0f.

Has anyone a formula to convert it back to the linear values between 0.0f and 1.0f?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: You should probably add the core-audio tag to this question to make it more findable for future readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

Several Apple examples use the following formula to convert the decibels into a linear range (from 0.0 to 1.0):

```
double percentage = pow (10, (0.05 * power));
```

where `power` is the value you get from one of the various level meter methods or functions, such as AVAudioPlayer's `averagePowerForChannel:`

Comment: I am quite surprised for the upvote, because this is the standard formula dB=20*log(lvl)......

Comment: @Brethlosze you are referring to the reverse formula, the OP asked for dB -> percentage.

Answer (score 8):

**Math behind the Linear and Logarithmic value conversion:**

**1. Linear to Decibel (logarithmic):**

```
decibelValue = 20.0f * log10(linearValue)
```

**Note:** log is base 10

Suppose the linear value in the form of percentage range from [ 0 (min vol) to 100 (max vol)] then the decibelValue for **half of the volume** (50%) is

```
decibelValue = 20.0f * log10(50.0f/100.0f) = -6 dB
```

***Full volume:***

```
decibelValue = 20.0f * log10(100.0f/100.0f) = 0 dB
```

***Complete mute:***

```
decibelValue = 20.0f * log10(0/100.0f) = -infinity
```

**2. Decibel(logarithmic) to Linear:**

```
LinearValue = pow(10.0f, decibelValue/20.0f)
```

Comment: I must add, that you must use the minimum measurable value instead of zero. Be known that 20.log10(xmax/xmin) is the definition of dynamic range. Hence. the Not Audible level is actually the Dynamic Range, not -infty.

Comment: What is the relevance of `20.0`?

Answer (score 2):

Apple uses a lookup table in their [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) sample that converts from dB to a linear value displayed on a level meter.

I moulded their calculation in a small routine; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16192481/1971013).