# How to calculate dBr from the volume on IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I am working on a "test your hearing application".

I know that half the amplitude is -6db.

I would like to know that when 1.0 is maximum volume using the AVAudioPlayer class, will setting the volume to 0.5 means that it plays at 50%, meaning a drop in relative db to -6db, if we used an ideal earphone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - AVAudioPlayer - convert decibel level into percent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512131/iphone-avaudioplayer-convert-decibel-level-into-percent)

Comment: Also, as Paul indicates in response to [How can I calculate audio dB level?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445756/how-can-i-calculate-audio-db-level), this will probably require calibration for the specific audio hardware you're using (both iOS device and type of headphones).

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks you for commenting. While it seems that one can get the average db value from the player, there is nothing about the actual hardware. What i would like to know is whatever or not setting the volume between 0.0 to 1.0 is a linear expression or follows some  curve. I am not talking about the actual sound produced by the headphone as they are not linear, normally not even close, but the actual analog headphone amp output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an excellent question.

I wouldn't be surprised if the range in AVAudioPlayer more closely matches that of the "standard leveling scale" for popular music.

[image]

Notice here that 0dB is pretty far up linearly in the range.  This is based on the history of the VU meter as described in [Level Practices (Part 2)](http://www.digido.com/level-practices-part-2-includes-the-k-system.html) and seen in this picture:

[image]

So, I don't know for sure, but my guess would be that AVAudioPlayer more closely matches these ranges.  You could always plug headphone jack of our iOS device into an application like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), [Logic](http://www.apple.com/logicpro/), or [Pro Tools](http://www.avid.com/US/products/family/pro-tools) and actually measure the signal coming out of your app as you sweep through the volume range in AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about doing this. But I would have to create a dummy load  (a resistor in parallel?) with the same impedance as the headphones (which btw are not totally flat from 0 to 20k hz). That way I could sweep from 0 to 20k hz while sweeping the volume.